# vb.net class structure for complex JSON strings

Tags: json, vb.net

Here's how my JSON string looks like:

```
[

{
"startTime":"2014-09-22T03:00Z",
"endTime":"2014-09-22T04:00Z",
"timeElapsed":60,
"employee":{
    "PictureIDImage":{"uri":"empPhoto01.png"},
    "EmpID":"203",
    "employeeId":"65487"
    },
"employeeId":"65487",
"department":{
    "departmentID":"12333",
    "rootId":"9921466",
    "seriesId":"9921466",
    "HelpCategories":["Consumer"],
    "PictureIDImage":{"uri":"photo01.png"},
    "entityType":"Show"
    }
},

{
"startTime":"2014-09-22T03:00Z",
"endTime":"2014-09-22T04:00Z",
"timeElapsed":60,
"employee":{
    "PictureIDImage":{"uri":"empPhoto01.png"},
    "EmpID":"203",
    "employeeId":"65487"
    },
"employeeId":"65487",
"department":{
    "departmentID":"12333",
    "rootId":"9921466",
    "seriesId":"9921466",
    "HelpCategories":["Consumer"],
    "PictureIDImage":{"uri":"photo01.png"},
    "entityType":"Show"
    }
}
]
```

I have created an Employee and Department classes. Then I have another class called Company that with all entities as well as a variable defined as Employee and Department. (due to sensitivity of the data I have scrubbed a lot of information. In case if something is messed up in the json string, I apologize!

Now, having said that when I do the following

```vb
Dim obj As List(Of StationAiring)
obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of StationAiring))(html)
```

> Error: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g.
>   {"name":"value"}) into type
>   'Listings_Matching.frmEmployeeMatching+Employee[]' because the type
>   requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly. To fix
>   this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or
>   change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g.
>   not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array
>   or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object.
>   JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON object. Path '[0].Employee.empID', line 1,
>   position 100.

Any assistance to point me in the right direction to fix the error / class definition is appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give you an accurate answer without seeing your Company class, but looking at the error message, it looks like **Employee** is defined as an array or List in your Company class.  I can see in your JSON that **employee** is **not** a JSON array. I suggest either (1) changing **Employee**  in your Company class accordingly, or (2) fix your JSON so that **employee** is an array, like

```
"employee":[{
"PictureIDImage":{"uri":"empPhoto01.png"},
"EmpID":"203",
"employeeId":"65487"
}],
```